# why does LSPACE(log space) complexity class exist but not logtime?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I noticed that in complexity classes, logspace class is defined but there is no logtime.

I was wondering how is that possible?

Normally, I would expect the opposite, It is possible to do a search query in an ordered list in time less than the time of iterating over all items (==> Logtime?). However you can't store a list in of size n in log(n) space...

So how come Logspace exists but not logtime? there's obviously something wrong with my reasoning.

Could someone please correct me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turing machines operating in logarithmic time cannot even read the entire input. This makes them rather uninteresting.

What you have in mind is not Turing machines, but random-access machines, for which logarithmic time does make sense. Indeed, the corresponding complexity class exists: [DLOGTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLOGTIME). It is most often used in the context of [DLOGTIME-uniform circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Uniformity). A related complexity class is ALOGTIME, which is the uniform version of NC¹. Buss famously proved that the formula evaluation problem is ALOGTIME-complete. For comparison, the circuit evaluation problem is P-complete.

Algorithms running in $o(n)$ time on random-access machines are known as *sublinear time algorithms*. Such algorithms also abound in the area of *data structures*.

Comment: Since the question also shows some confusion about logspace, it might be worth mentioning that in the Turing machine model, the "logarithmic space" corresponds to the size of a working tape **additionally** to the input tape.

Comment: @ttnick, the reason I did not accept this answer immediately was because it lacked the extra information you just mentioned! Now I'm good, I have my answer. Thank you both!